Mathematica 11.3.0, .nb file running for too long on Windows 10
I am doing simple calculation in Mathematica 11.3.0 on Windows 10. Here is my code:
g[n_] := 1/2 (Power[n + Sqrt[n^2 - 1/27]   , (3)^-1] + Power[n - Sqrt[n^2 - 1/27], (3)^-1]), h[n_] := (Sqrt[n] + Sqrt[n + 16 (Sqrt[n] + 1)])/8 - g[n], Solve[h[n] == 0, n] // N

However my .nb file keeps running for hours and not giving any results. Before it I never had this type of problem with Mathematica. I don't know what went wrong with my software.
Based on the answer given here, I opened my Mathematica 11.3.0 Kernel and typed the
following:

PacletSiteUpdate /@ PacletSites[]
PacletUpdate["EntityFramework"]

But I am getting the output saying that

{PacletSite[http://pacletserver.wolfram.com, Wolfram Research Paclet Server, Local -> False]}

Nothing is solving my problem. How can I fix this? I have a very little knowledge of computers. Can sombody help me resolving this issue?

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

g[n_] := 1/2*((n - Sqrt[-(1/27) + n^2])^(1/3) + 
    (n + Sqrt[-(1/27) + n^2])^(1/3))

h[n_] := (Sqrt[n] + Sqrt[n + 16  (Sqrt[n] + 1)])/8 - g[n]

Use NSolve
(sol = NSolve[h[n] == 0, n, WorkingPrecision -> 50]) // N

(* {{n -> -3.03095 - 11.67 I}, {n -> -3.03095 + 11.67 I}, {n -> 0.}} *)

Verifying,
h[n] == 0 /. sol // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)

